# Is the picture memory size related to the size of the image file?

Tags: android, image, memory

Is the picture memory size related to the size of the image file?I mean that if I have two pictures with diferent file size such as 1M,10M and I load them in a same imageview(in android) with the same resolution（1024*768）,are they taking up the same amount of memory？

Dose the memory size only depends on this  formulae——resolution* The number of bytes occupied by one pixel?

And so what's the diference between two images with diferent file size?(a 30M image and a 5M taken by a smartphone)

Comment: totally no difference in RAM they take. Only resolution matters, as they are loaded as 2D array of pixels